# The Process Cannot Access The File...Because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, .net

I'm taking a file and doing 2 things to it. Resizing it and placing it in a picturebox, then resizing it again and saving it.

The first resize operation goes well after dropping it into the window as a thumbnail, however after it has been resized, the second resize operation fails saying its in use.

From my understanding Im not closing the file or stream. A solution to this is the "using" command, but no matter where I put it, I get errors.

First Resize Code:

```
    private void Form1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] droppedfiles = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
        PB_Picture.Image = ScaleImage(Image.FromFile(droppedfiles[0]), 180, 140);
    }
```

I tried:

```
    private void Form1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        using (string[] droppedfiles = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop));
        PB_Picture.Image = ScaleImage(Image.FromFile(droppedfiles[0]), 180, 140);
    }
```

But get a number of errors.

[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l08Wx.png)

Comment: Well to start, you can't use an array in a `using` statement because it does not implement IDisposable. Try removing the using statement.

Comment: Where is the second resize operation?

Comment: You must dispose the image returned from `Image.FromFile`, not your array of strings.

Comment: Please include the errors as text, not as an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing where the second resize operation is I can't be certain, but this should fix your issue.

```
private void Form1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    string[] droppedfiles = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
    using (var image = Image.FromFile(droppedfiles[0])){
        PB_Picture.Image = ScaleImage(image, 180, 140);
    }
}
```

Comment: This was perfect. I knew I was close! Thanks so much!

Answer (score -1):

The `using` statement is not correct:

```
private void Form1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    using(string[] droppedfiles = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop)){
        PB_Picture.Image = ScaleImage(Image.FromFile(droppedfiles[0]), 180, 140);
    }
}
```

Comment: And how did your edits help it? This won't even build.